# How to select only first rows that satisfies conditions?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, group-by

I'm doing a join between two tables and adding a condition want to obtain only the first row that satisfie the join condition and the "extern" condition too.

This query for example:

```
select * from PRMPROFILE p, user v
where 
p.id = v.profile
and p.language = 0
and v.userid like '%TEST%';
```

First of all, i want to know how to *group the result of this inner join using the profile (v.profile or p.id)*. After that how to show only the first appearence for each group.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected results? And you need to define what makes a particular row the 'first' match.

Comment: What do you mean "extern" condition? Have you considered using `and ROWNUM=1`([see Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm))? Addendum: This will provide you with only 1 matching result but it may not be consistent across queries. See also [ROWID](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm).

Comment: "extern" condition is a condition different than the joining condition. The join are not explicit and it takes some conditions in the where clause.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an analytic query for this:

```
select *
from (
    select p.*, v.*,
        row_number() over (partition by p.id order by v.userid) as rn
    from prmprofile p
    join user v on v.profile = p.id
    where p.language = 0
    and v.userid like '%TEST%'
)
where rn = 1;
```

The inner query gets all the data (but using `*` isn't ideal), and adds an extra column that assigns a row number sequence across each `p.id` value. They have to be ordered by something, and you haven't said what makes a particular row 'first', so I've guessed as user ID - you can of course change that to something more appropriate, that will give consistent results when the query is rerun. (You can look at `rank` and `dense_rank` for alternative methods to pick the 'first' row).

The outer query just restricts the result set to those where the extra column has the value `1`, which will give you one row for every `p.id`.

Another approach would be to use a subquery to identify the 'first' row and join to that, but it isn't clear what the criteria would be and if it would be selective enough.

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez - do your `profile` and `user` tables have column with the same name? If so you'll need to list them all explicitly rather than using `*`, and alias the duplicates so they appear to have different names (assuming you actually want to retrieve both).

Comment: There are no columns with the same name. I can do the join without any problem: select * 
from prmprofile p
join user v on v.profil = p.id
where p.langue = 0
and v.userid like '%TEST%';

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez - the join would still work with duplicates, but the outer `select` I'm using would give that error if they both had a column called `name`, for example (or one has `rn`). Please add the table definitions to the question.

Comment: Sorry, there is a column in botth tables with the same name. Is there any easy option to "print" all column except one ?? But that solve the query you posted. Thanks.

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez - no, I'm afraid not, you need to list them all individually.

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
select * from(
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by v.userid order by v.userid) RNum
  from PRMPROFILE p, user v
  where 
  p.id = v.profile
  and p.language = 0
  and v.userid like '%TEST%'
  )x 
where RNum=1;
```

Comment: But doesn't group the resulting joining table to show only the first appearance of each group.

Comment: Which is the `group` column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LIMIT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) keyword.

```
select * from PRMPROFILE p, user v
where 
p.id = v.profile
and p.language = 0
and v.userid like '%TEST%'
limit 1
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `LIMIT` (until 12c, apparently). It also wouldn't address the 'grouping' part of the question; the OP wants one row per profile ID, not a single row for the whole query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from PRMPROFILE p, user v
where p.id = v.profile and p.language = 0
and v.userid like '%TEST%'
fetch first 1 row only
```

Answer (score 0):

It will display only the top result

```
select top 1 * from PRMPROFILE p, user v
where 
    p.id = v.profile
    and p.language = 0
    and v.userid like '%TEST%';
```

Comment: Does Oracle have that syntax?

Comment: i am sorry. i gave it for sql