# Select unique value based on a couple of columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a query that I have built as follows

```sql
SELECT brand, model, buyer_rate, DATE_ADD(finish_dt, INTERVAL 33 HOUR), bid_price, g.status, ga.idx AS gai, ab.idx as abi 
FROM auction_bid ab 
INNER JOIN goods_auction ga ON ab.goods_auction_idx=ga.idx 
INNER JOIN auction_info ai ON ga.auction_info_idx=ai.idx 
INNER JOIN goods g ON ai.goods_idx= g.idx 
INNER JOIN user u on g.user_idx=u.idx 
WHERE g.status='A008' AND DATEDIFF(Now(), ab.created_at)<5 GROUP BY bid_price DESC, ab.created_at
```

The result of the query is something like the picture below
[image]

The result that I am hoping to retrieve is the maximum bid_price value for the same brand and model.

So in this case I would like to retrieve the 1st and 10th row.

Would there be any way to edit my existing query to get this desired result.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select only first rows that satisfies conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034226/how-to-select-only-first-rows-that-satisfies-conditions)

Comment: @Luuk Thanks for your feedback! Seems to have worked thanks